# Nestjs-Prisma Soft Delete

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I want to implement Soft delete while using Prisma, So any could recommend Stable Soft delete package to use it direct, as make custom implementation require many cases to be covered.

Answer (score 0):

I found this package [prisma-soft-delete-middleware](https://github.com/olivierwilkinson/prisma-soft-delete-middleware?tab=readme-ov-file), it looks like this handles all the scenarios